# iOS gamekit/bluetooth data streaming

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, gamekit, nsstream

I have a written a program using gamekit/bluetooth to transfer low quality video using compressed jpegs from one iOS device to another.  I do already realize that gamekit/bluetooth should not be used for this purpose (for small chunks of data) but it does indeed work well streaming 15 low quality compressed jpegs/second with little to no latency.

The question I have is once I increase either the quality or frame rate from the iOS device sender to the iOS receiver, a lag or delay will occur and will no longer be real time.  If there is a delay, I'd like somehow for the sending iOS device to discard frames so that the receiver can catchup or for the receiver to ignore the backlog queue.

In GameKit I have set the session mode to use GKSendDataUnreliable to see if it could help, but to no avail.

If delays occur, what is the best solution and correct approach to discard the frames (jpegs) so that the iOS receiver can then catch up back to real time?  Would the sender need to stop transmission for a period of time or is there something that receiving client can do to discard the accumulating queue.

I've used NSStream before as well, and while using wifi allows for greater bandwidth, the same problem will still occur in terms of delays if too much data is being transmitted.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It might help to see some of the code for your frame queue, etc. You are probably right in that you will either need to stop the transmission or discard frames in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not attach a timestamp to each jpg (time since epoch perhaps) so the receiving client will ignore all images that are not within a given timeframe.

Also you could have the receiving client respond back with simple acknowledgement packets indicating that a jpg has been received. If the sending client hasn't received an acknowledge packet within a given timeframe it discards all images it was going to send and starts from scratch.

With this solution if the receiving client falls X seconds behind the sender it will stop sending acknowledgement packets and discard all incoming data until the sender throws out everything in its queue and starts sending "live" frames again.